# How to Hide or Change Apache server ip using Proxy

Tags: apache, proxy

Is there any way to hide Apache Server ip using proxy or any thing?
i saw many website that hosted on server with Private IP Address like :  10.10.34.34  and ...
How This Possible?
it can protect our server from ddos attack?

Answer (score 1):

you can bind your domain to a switch,and switch forward those packet to your real server.